# Is javascript interval clear?

Tags: javascript

I'm stuck with such thing:
I have var calls update_interval, and I start/stop my intervals with it.
My problem is to understand if interval clear or not.
Smth like:
 clearInterval(update_interval);
 update_interval = false/null/undefined 
is not counting due to the specific of my project.
Any ideas?

Comment: So basically you question is: How do you determine if an interval is cancelled or still running?

Comment: put your interval into a variable var myVar = setInterval(function(){myTimer()}, 1000);  then push it into an array, and scan the array to see if it is null or not

Comment: @epascarello, exactly!

Comment: @PaulBastide, after clearInterval(myVar) myVar won't be null, so why array will be?

Comment: you can just iterate over the array to check.

Answer (score 0):

Theres is no built-in mechanism to check whether a timeout has completed or not. You will have to do it yourself, here is a minimal example:

```
var pending = true;
var timer = setTimeout(function() {
    /* do some stuff */
    pending = false;
}, 5000);
```

You can then check whether the timed function is done running or not:

```
if (pending) {
    // hasn't run yet
}
else {
    // is done running
}
```

Comment: Thnks, @Jean-Karim Bockstael. But it isn't what I'm looking for. There are lots of places where several intervals starting or cleaning, I can find each one, but tommorow anybody can add one, and then my mechanizm will broke.